# Как обратиться к элементу, на который повешено событие

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

В случае с нативным js я могу получить элемент через `this`:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Но я работаю с react, код выглядит как-то так:

```
function App() {
  function eventFunction(ev) {
    console.log(this, ev.target); // undefined, <p>text</p>
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={eventFunction}>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Как в таком случае обратиться к элементу, на который повесили событие или может есть более правильный способ вешать события в react?

Comment: Вообще не знаком с React, но [здесь](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) говорится, что в обработчик события передаётся [SyntheticEvent](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/events.html) у которого имеется DOMEventTarget currentTarget. Не оно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как алтернатива

```
    export const App = () => {
  //хук для привязки контекста
  const myRef = useRef()
  

  function eventFunction(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(myRef.current)
  }

  return (
      <div ref={myRef} onClick={eventFunction}>
        <p>text1</p>
      </div>
  );
}
```

плюс по идее все ивенты оборачиваются в реактовские так что обращение идет через virtual dom